# Как установить яркость экрана в android приложении ниже минимальной?

Tags: java, android

Как установить яркость экрана в android приложении ниже минимальной?

Comment: о, мне тоже интересно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Невозможно. А даже, если можно, то установится не только в вашем приложении и без `root` это сделать нельзя. Зато можно реализовать ночной режим. Через `FrameLayout` поставьте поверх всей разметки `LinearLayout` с черным `background`. А чтобы яркость "сделать ниже минимальной" - управляйте степенью прозрачности бэкграунда

Comment: круто, по поводу черного background, телефон начнет медленнее разряжаться? Или он будет "светиться" черным?) если такое вообще бывает, я не шарю)

Comment: я помню добавлял в одно приложение такой функционал, пользователи в основном играли ночью, там привилегии были. не жаловались, все устраивало. нет, не светится) отличный ночной режим. единственное - светилось как обычно все, что не входило в разметку - статусбар и клавиатура. Первое я убрал для фуллскрина, с клавой решил смириться))

Comment: ясно, интересно, но я просто видел такую фишку: в Pokemon Go есть режим сохранения энергии, так вот там можно наклонить телефон и экран тухнет полностью на 100%, интересно было бы узнать реализацию.

Comment: 100% это работает так же как и делал я. А вообще  заинтересовало - может декомпилировать, найти этот код?

Comment: я думаю декомпилить будет сложно, дохера денег заработали, наверное защиту норм уже сделали, хоть недавно игра вышла. https://trashbox.ru/link/pokemon-go-android вот если что можно скачать, но я не умею декомпилить

Comment: да и код не найдешь, запутаешься. нигде больше не видели такого?

Comment: увы, но нет, нигде не видел.